# Dynamic field rendering depends on object fields in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, administration, dynamic-binding

I got a requirement that the LWC form fields rendering has to be dynamic. Say if I add a text box field in object then in front end(LWC), it has to come automatically without any coding in LWC. Some how I achieved this using fieldset concept. Is it the only option in salesforce or is there any other option that can be leveraged?

Some practical difficulty what I am facing is through this I cant able to achieve radio-group or checkbox-group functionality because there is no such field type in salesforce.

Comment: Have you considered use of [Dynamic Forms in the Winter '21 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_forms_ga.htm)? Note that this won't help with radio groups and checkbox groups that cannot be realized without code AFAIK.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for your reply. Actually we are not using Record page concept in our application and its like kind of single page application like angular. Seems Dynamic forms can be used only in record pages.

Comment: OK, so you will need to write your own LWC using your own custom configuration that drives the creation of radio/checkbox groups.

Comment: Absolutely @PhilW. I explored and found one way as "fieldset" .so before start working on fieldset concept  just want to know is there any other approach also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst field sets allow an admin to use built-in configuration capabilities and their content is readily accessible for use in custom code, they do not define groups of fields specifically.

You have various options available:

1. Use multiple field sets with constructed API names, e.g. 'my_spa_fields_group_' plus a number, to allow definition of field groups. You can use the field sets' labels to label the groups of fields on the UI. Where a group only contains Checkbox fields you can make it a radio group. With slightly different naming you could control if it should be a radio group or just a checkbox group.
2. Use a specifically named layout for a given type of object to define sections that operate similarly, reading the layout details using the metadata API from Apex and returning the details back to your LWC for rendering.
3. Create your own Custom Metadata Type containing a definition of the required UI for a given type of object. This is an approach we have adopted for configuring sophisticated LWC components, where we have a JSON schema and the Custom Metadata Type then contains JSON conforming to that schema. The LWC components have a property that accepts the name of one of the CMT records.

The big advantage of the last approach is flexibility. You can add lots more options as you see fit. The downside is that there's no nice visual editing of the JSON and such editing is best done in a schema-aware editor (such as VSCode or IntelliJ IDEA) since these can validate and provide auto-completion support.

The advantage of the first approach is that the admin can create multiple field sets to represent groupings in your UI so you can present a "section" in your UI with a title (created from the field set's label) and show the fields in the field set in that "section". Ordering of sections relies, for example, on the field set API name ordering. You might, for example, have your LWC use all field sets that have an API name starting "my_spa_fields_". Let's assume the admin then creates the following:

- "my_spa_fields_30" labelled "Preferences"

  - has only Checkbox fields that represent user preferences, where the user can check as many as they like (this checkbox group behaviour happens because the name doesn't end "radio"), e.g. fields K, O and I
- "my_spa_fields_10" labelled "Details"

  - has various general fields added to it by the admin, e.g. fields X and E
- "my_spa_fields_20_radio" labelled "Selected Station"

  - has only Checkbox fields that represent stations from which only one station can be selected (this radio button behaviour happens because of the suffix on the name), e.g. fields F, H, A and Y

Your LWC can then show the page with the sections ordered by API name, and thus with:

**Details**

fieldX

fieldE

**Selected Station**

(o) fieldF

( ) fieldH

( ) fieldA

( ) fieldY

**Preferences**

[X] fieldK

[X] fieldO

[ ] fieldI

Comment: Actually my requirement is Admin will add a field in object and it has to be rendered in LWC. So better I will consider 1) and 2) as admin can do easily. Can you please give some brief idea on point # 1 as I am not able to understand things clearly

Comment: So how I can all the field sets?. Suppose say if I have three field set means do I have to make three calls , if so how I can arrange the order of field sets?

Comment: Look at [DescribeSobjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm).fieldSets.getMap(). You can iterate the keys in the map to find those that match the name pattern, then just sort them to get the required order. It is really not hard. Just look at the APIs available to you in Apex and remember you can write your own wire services for LWCs.